# While typing in a text input field, print content replacing dots

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, onkeyup

I need rewrite the content of some input into another using 'onkeyup' and replacing the '.' (dots) os the values. Right now, just onkeyup feature of my code runs. How can I do for delivery a 'clear' string (without dots) to another input?

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var minValue = $('money-min-value');

        minValue.onkeyup = function(){
            var clearMinValue = '';
            clearMinValue = minValue.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g,'');
            $('meta_property_sell_price1').value = clearMinValue;
        }   
    });
</script>
```

Comment: can't get u..can you make it clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this fix it?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('#money-min-value').on('keyup',function() {
    var clearMinValue = '';
    clearMinValue = $(this).val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g, '');
    $('#meta_property_sell_price1').val(clearMinValue);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>#money-min-value <input type="text" id="money-min-value" ></label><br>
<label>#meta_property_sell_price1 <input type="text" id="meta_property_sell_price1" ></label>
```

Comment: Yeah :D Glad that helped you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the jQuery [`keyup`](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) function like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.money-min-value').on('keyup', function() {
     var clearMinValue = '';
     clearMinValue = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g, ' ');
     $('.meta_property_sell_price1').val(clearMinValue);  //used jquery's val() here
   });
 });
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5s4sw9vg/)

NOTE: *you also need to specify `.` or `#` for both `money-min-value` and `meta_property_sell_price1` whether they are `class` or `id`.*

Comment: Thank you! Your solution works! But I had to give my point for those who did first.

Comment: @JeffersonVasconcelos: no issues :) you are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript's [`.replace`](http://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_replace.asp) should do the trick for you.

So it would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var minValue = $('money-min-value');

        minValue.onkeyup = function(){
            var clearMinValue = '';
            clearMinValue = minValue.replace(/\./gi, '');
            $('meta_property_sell_price1').value = clearMinValue;
        }   
    });
</script>
```

The `\` tells the regex that `.` should be treated like a `.` and not like a part of the regex. Thus looking only for `.` and replacing it with "" blank.